# Activity crashing while passing in text values and trying to display

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Get the user input:

```
Intent intentTrashcanLocation = new Intent(this, TrashcanLocationActivity.class);           
EditText editWidth = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dimvalWidth);
EditText editLength = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dimvalLength);
String width = editWidth.getText().toString();
String length = editLength.getText().toString();
intentTrashcanLocation.putExtra("widthValue", width);
intentTrashcanLocation.putExtra("lengthValue", length);
startActivity(intentTrashcanLocation);
```

Receive and display:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_trashcan_location);        
Intent parentintent = getIntent();
Bundle dimval = parentintent.getExtras();
String width = (String)dimval.get("widthValue");    
String length = (String)dimval.get("lengthValue");
TextView widthtext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.widthView);
TextView lengthtext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lengthView);
widthtext.setText(width);
lengthtext.setText(length);
```

When I run the program and give the text input and proceed to next activity,
the program crashes. Getting errors:

```
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.trash2/com.example.trash2.TrashcanLocationActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    at com.example.trash2.TrashcanLocationActivity.onCreate(TrashcanLocationActivity.java:36)
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    ... 11 more
```

I am pretty new at this and any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Edit:
This is activity_trashcan_location:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.trash2.TrashcanLocationActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

and fragment_trashcan_location:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/interface_bg"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.trash2.TrashcanLocationActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:text="Bluetooth Trashcan"
    android:textAppearance="@style/AppTheme"
    android:textSize="60dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="- Settings: Trashcan Location?"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="40dp" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/widthView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lengthView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />      

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="Finish"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:onClick="doMain" />
```

Comment: can you tell where do you have this `String width = editWidth.getText().toString();` in `onCreate`?

Comment: Whats at line TrashcanLocationActivity.java:36 (line 36)

Comment: @Diletante please what is at line 36 of TrashcanLocationActivity ??

Comment: Hi Raghunandan ! it's at line 20 of SettingsActivity, which is the parent activity of TrashcanLocationActivity.
Hi xBroak and LisaAnne ! at line 36, it's widthtext.setText(width);

Comment: @Diletante post `activity_trashcan_location.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `activity_trashcan_location` layout does not contain the views `widthView` and `lengthView`. Instead they are in the fragment layout, and it won't be a part of your activity's view hierarchy in activity `onCreate()`.

To fix it, either

- move the code that touches the views to the fragment, e.g. its `onCreateView()`, or
- move the views that need to be touched to the activity layout.

Comment: Oh so to clarify... activity_xxx is the main page, and fragment_xxx is just a "fragment" of that page? So in my case, 1 fragment is filling up this main page, but all the systematic stuff should be done on the activity_xxx ?

Comment: From the activity view hierarchy point of view (where activity `findViewById()` works), the fragment will be part of that hierarchy eventually but not yet in activity `onCreate()`.

Comment: Okay, this helped a lot! I probably need to fix a lot before I can test this.. Thanks!

Comment: So i'm trying to do the second option that you provided. Does the syntax change between the fragment and activity? Just cutting the relevant Textview code from fragment and pasting in the activity doesn't seem to do the job..

Comment: In `onCreateView()` you usually inflate the fragment view. Call `findViewById()` on the view you just inflated.

Comment: So the first option is more recommended? 
When I tried it it gives me an error saying that I cannot make static reference to the non-static method findViewByID :(

Comment: Oh.. yes the second option you asked about.. Copy the layout elements to the other layout file. That should do it. But the first option is more recommended (though it has slightly steeper learning curve). You inflate the `view` and then call `view.findViewById(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

All you have is a `FrameLayout`in `activity_trashcan_location.xml`.

But you initialize `TextView's` in the Activtiy which leads to `NullPointerException`

The TextView's belong to the `FragmentLayout`. So you need to initialize textview in Fragment.

Get the value in Activtiy via intent and then communicate to Activity

Edit:

In Activity

```
String length = (String)dimval.get("lengthValue");
MyFragment newFragment = new MyFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fcontainer, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null); // If you want to add it to backstack
transaction.commit();
```

Then use the code by prosper k

[Send data from activity to fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Then in Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trashcan_location, container, false);

TextView widthtext = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.widthView);
TextView lengthtext = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lengthView);
// set text to textView here
return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Yes.. I seem to have misunderstood some stuff from the root. Repeated from the bottom:
Oh so to clarify... activity_xxx is the main page, and fragment_xxx is just a "fragment" of that page? So in my case, 1 fragment is filling up this main page, but all the systematic stuff should be done on the activity_xxx ?

Comment: @Diletante no you are wrong. Fragment is attached to the Activity. However the views belong to the Fragment. So the intialization of view must be in Fragment

Comment: Oh.. I think I am partially understanding it but not completely. I think I test this stuff out to understand it. Thank you so much

Comment: @Diletante `findViewById` looks for a view with the id in the current view hierarchy. So if your activity layout set to the activity does not contain those view you end up in NPE>

Comment: I am so sorry both you and laalto helped me a lot but I had to choose the one that was posted just a bit earlier... Thanks again!

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks let me try this out too

Answer (score 1):

Send them like that:

```
Intent intentTrashcanLocation = new Intent(this, TrashcanLocationActivity.class);           
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("widthValue", width);
bundle.putString("lengthValue", length);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Get them like that:

```
Bundle bundle= this.getIntent().getExtras();
String width = (String)bundle.getString("widthValue");    
String length = (String)bundle.getString("lengthValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your "get user code" code:

1. Make sure you have a call to setContentView(R.layout.activity_trashcan_location) before the findViewById() calls. Otherwise, the findViewById() calls won't find anything, and return null.
2. Make sure your activity_trashcan_location layout actually has components with the **dimvalWidth** and **dimvalLength** IDs. If those IDs are not assigned to a component in the layout file, the corresponding findViewById() call will also return null.

Comment: 1. I call setContentView in the OnCreate method, and call findViewById in the method that is called when the button is pressed on this activity.. would this not work?

Comment: Yes. Your question did not provide enough code to let me know this. In the future, you should provide much more code. For example, if your exception stack trace says the exception was thrown at line n, you should provide enough information so that we can identify line n.

Comment: I will keep this in mind, sorry about the confusion!

Answer (score -2):

you need a handler to set a textview.... code to follow

declare vars before oncreate

```
Handler handler;
    private int i;
```

in oncreate:

```
i = 0;
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(mUpdate);
```

and the actuall method

```
Runnable mUpdate = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


            yourtextview.setText("text you want to see");

            i++;

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
```

Comment: Handler? Why is that required??. Its not required at all

Comment: you cant update the ui without a handler or asynctask. handler is easier( for me)

Comment: You cannot update ui from a non ui thread. Here in op's case that is not the case. Your totally wrong and misunderstood the use of Handler. I suggest you read the docs about ui thread and handlers

Comment: umm yes you can, i do it all the time. try the code before you tell me im wrong. lol. it may not be how you do it, but it is a sloution and will fix the problem. and ive read those docs, over and over.....

Comment: Why Handler is not required. 1. read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html 2. read Threads @ http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: After reading those 2 links come back and then say if i am wrong or not

Comment: read em several times. part of the beauty of code is bieng able to think outside the box. i have a handler that updates my ui with about..... 100 textviews, and a few imageviews, it also set my layouts visiblity for about 15 layouts. just because its not how you use it dosnt make it wrong, it is stable and quick.

Comment: (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.     (such as the uithread)

Comment: You don't get the point there is no need for a handler. well i am not here to argue. good luck

Comment: 03-29 12:33:57.418: E/AndroidRuntime(28049):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)